# How do I automatically load my ~/.zprofile when I log in?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I've started using zsh for my login shell.

I've create an a `~/.zprofile`, but in order for it to be put into effect, I have to manually source it.

How can I have my settings load automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands from `~/.zprofile` are only read if the shell is a login shell. Did you set zsh as your default shell using `cshsh` or just in the preferences of the terminal emulator? If the former, logging out and back in should do the trick (although, the file will be only read when you actually perform the login, not when you start a new shell), or you have to tell your terminal emulator to execute the shell as a login shell. If you are using `gnome-terminal`, go to `Edit->Profile Preferences`, select the `Title and command` tab and check the `Run command as a login shell` box.

Comment: Indeed I did use cssh to set my login shell.Editing gnome-terminals preferences as per your suggestion seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Now, suppose I develop something like `gnome-terminal`. What do **I** have to do in order to *run zsh as a login shell?* Is it enough to just set its `argv[0]` to `-`, or are there more steps?

Comment: @ulidtko `zsh --help` will tell you that it is `zsh --login`. Same goes for bash, ash, sh, csh, tcsh, fish...